# How can I simplify a nested loop in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, nested-loops

I want to simplify my code, because it is very time consuming. In my problem, R is a bout 4000, so *corr*  function should be call for more than 16000000 times. haw can I simplify this code?

```
for i=1:R

    for j=1:R

        Red1 = Red1 + abs(corr (SelectedData,i,j));

    end

end
```

edit: So, I should say that, *corr* function is written by me and it compute correlation between two features.

and this is my *corr* function:

```
function corr = corr (X, i, j)

    covariance = (cov((X(:,i)),(X(:,j))));

    corr = (covariance(1,2))/((sqrt(var(X(:,i)))) * (sqrt(var(X(:,j)))) );


end
```

Comment: First, it looks like you are using `correlation` function in the wrong way: it must contain 4 arguments (5th is not necessary). Look at this [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/antenna/ref/correlation.html?searchHighlight=correlation&s_tid=doc_srchtitle).
And the second: `correlation` cannot works for `i` and `j` of array type, so I think we can avoid loop using some `arrayfun` or `bsxfun` but we still have to use `correlation` for 16m times (4000*4000)... But I'm not sure here :)

Comment: thank you for your reply @Mikhail_Sam; but corrlation function is a function that written by me. I have edited my question.

Comment: Ah, okay! Than I advise you to rename it for avoiding overwriting built-in function name. To help you we need to see it's code: maybe we can vectorize some actions into it!

Comment: thank you for your advice @Mikhail_Sam; I corrected it; and I have added my corr function

Comment: I'm not joking  but `corr` is built in function too: [MATLAB doc](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/corr.html) :D
Ok, now let's try to workaround for you function...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a vectorized version:

```
C = cov(SelectedData);
V = sqrt(diag(C));
VP2 = bsxfun(@times,V,V.');
CORR = C ./ VP2;
Red1 = sum(abs(CORR(:)));
```

Comment: Glad if it can help!